# php SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, ssl

Below code are taken from Elephant.io client.php handshake method.

```
        $ch = curl_init($this->socketIOUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    if (!$this->checkSslPeer)
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    if (!is_null($this->handshakeTimeout)) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS, $this->handshakeTimeout);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, $this->handshakeTimeout);
    }

    if ($this->origin) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            $this->getOrigin()
        ));
    }

    if ($this->sendCookie && $this->cookie) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $this->cookie);
    }       
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);     // from here below 4 lines seems problem
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAPATH, "/etc/ssl/certs/");

    $res = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($res === false || $res === '') {
        throw new \Exception(curl_error($ch)); // here throws exception
    }
```

This code throws exception.
SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate.

I have tried with command
openssl s_client -showcerts -CApath /etc/ssl/certs -connect
amallu.com:443 -servername amallu.com
it returns ok.

Please help to resolve

Comment: With `openssl s_client` you are using `/etc/ssl/certs` as CA path while within your PHP code you are using `/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem`. If you want to get the same result I recommend to use the same path.

Comment: Hi steffen, thanks for your reply. I have tried that too..its not working

Comment: Which version of curl are you using? Maybe it is not using SNI (i.e. the `-servername` option in `openssl s_client`)

Comment: hi stefeen curl version is 7.35

Comment: To what value is `$this->socketIOUrl` exactly set in your code?